# How to get a javascript table into google sheets?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get this leaderboard table into google sheets and have been stuck on what needs to be done. Hoping someone can help. Thanks!

https://www.rickrungood.com/pga-live-leaderboard/

Here's the javascript page of it:

https://leaderboard.dfsondemand.com/

Comment: Use that big json file of all the data. You need to convert that into a .csv file. Then you can upload the csv into google sheets.

Comment: Do you know the steps to do this? Sorry I'm just really lost with this. I need the leaderboard to be able to update on google sheets as it does on the website. Is that possible?

Comment: Apparently you can import .html files directly into google sheets. Download your second link, and import it as data into google sheets.

If you want it to update automatically, you'll have to write a little script to do the downloading and uploading every time.

Comment: Nope, this is the wrong site for that.